# I am being restricted on some app downloads by content filtering

Tags: applications, content-filter

Since yesterday my phone has been running slow....kicking me off sites.... or not signal. So I installed a cache cleaner and a virus protection app last night. My phone then began to run faster and work better but then while attempting to download apps (including ones I had already previously had)I would get notices saying that my content filter would not allow me to download I had no idea what this meant so I ignored it until in finally looked it up on Google. I did not set up a content filter on my phone and can not figure out how to fix it if anyone has any idea please let me know thank you

Comment: Speaking from my own experience, you shouldn't be able to see an app if the app falls outside the content filter since it partially beats the purpose of having a filter. Regardless of it, Google has a guide [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1075738?hl=en-IN) for how to change the content filter in Play Store settings. Also, would you mind to [edit] your question and mention the names(with links) of cache cleaner and virus protections app?

Answer (score 0):

In the Playstore app, head over to settings> content filtering and tick all the boxes in it.This should turn off content filtering.

If youve forgotten the PIN, you can reset the Content Filter pin by clearing the app data for the Play Store. This will clear the pin and also remove the filter.

- Go to Settings > Apps
- Tap on "Google Play Store" 
  -Tap the "Clear Data" button.